# An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred, this error appear , I try to insert this data in table in database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I'm getting this error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Must declare the scalar variable "@name".

when running my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection openCon = new SqlConnection("data source=10.10.20.20;initial catalog=YOUS1;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=secret ;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"))
    {
        var saveStaff = "INSERT INTO Ruser(ID, Name, Lname, pass)VALUES(@ID,@name,@lanme,@pass);";

        using (SqlCommand querySaveStaff = new SqlCommand(saveStaff))
        {
            try
            {
                // Your insert code here
                querySaveStaff.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                querySaveStaff.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", "33");
                querySaveStaff.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lanme", "abc");
                querySaveStaff.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", "abc");

                openCon.Open();
                Response.Write("User Registration successful");
                var result = querySaveStaff.ExecuteScalar();
                openCon.Open();
            }
            catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException sqlException)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(sqlException.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using `@name` in your `INSERT` statement (in the `VALUES` section) - but you never **specify** a parameter for `@name` --> you need to define and provide values for ***ALL*** parameters in your query!

Comment: In addition to what marc wrote, a must read: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Answer (score 1):

Error say that you are missing parameter @name in you statment

```
var saveStaff = "INSERT INTO Ruser(ID, Name, Lname, pass)VALUES(@ID,@name,@lanme,@pass);";
```

just add this:

```
querySaveStaff.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "abc");
```